# Import from Excel with panda but missing the index header

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, header, missing-data

I would like to use this data from xlsx :

```
               Fe    Mg    Al     Si     P     S     K     Ca     Ti
          5   0.80  2.09  3.49   7.05  0.19  0.07  0.13  84.28   1.90
          5   0.75  2.69  3.91  12.42  0.13  0.09  0.18  78.18   1.64
          3   0.87  2.66  3.71   7.64  0.17  0.05  0.12  82.97   1.81
               ...............
```

But when I imported :

```
file = 'test.xlsx'
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
df1 = xl.parse('Sheet1')
```

and than try to give a name to the 0. column but instead I can only renaming the Fe to Fabric:

```
new_columns = df1.columns.values;
new_columns[0] = 'Fabric';
df1.columns = new_columns
```

This is what I get:

```
            Fabric    Mg    Al     Si     P     S     K     Ca     Ti
          5   0.80  2.09  3.49   7.05  0.19  0.07  0.13  84.28   1.90
          5   0.75  2.69  3.91  12.42  0.13  0.09  0.18  78.18   1.64
          3   0.87  2.66  3.71   7.64  0.17  0.05  0.12  82.97   1.81
```

Instead of this [ :) ] :

```
     Fabric Fe    Mg    Al     Si     P     S     K     Ca     Ti
        5   0.80  2.09  3.49   7.05  0.19  0.07  0.13  84.28   1.90
        5   0.75  2.69  3.91  12.42  0.13  0.09  0.18  78.18   1.64
        3   0.87  2.66  3.71   7.64  0.17  0.05  0.12  82.97   1.81
```

I think I missing some basic stuff in here, but when I try to search for this I had no luck, so please If you have an idea for this , help :) . Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Fabric` looks like the index to your dataframe.  You are probably best of resetting it and then renaming your columns.

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1.columns =['Fabric'] + df1.columns[1:].tolist()
```

Comment: It seems good , the index had been made, but when I tried the 2. code of line it is give me this : 
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 10 elements, new values have 9 elements.   

thank you by the way !

Comment: Make sure you reassign or else do it inplace, i.e. `df1.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I suffer similar in cases where I don't know the name or number of columns ahead of time (only that the first unnamed column should have been "datetime").

In that case I read the date, and use ***.rename()*** to rename `Unnamed: 0` to what it should be:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(filepath)
df1.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'datetime'}, inplace=True)
df1.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
```